# How to make an iFrame go fullscreen with JS from its inside?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iFrame content that I use on third party websites.

I'm trying to get this iFrame content to go in full-screen browser mode.
This works OK when using the content alone as main document, but not on these third party websites (lms), that have often several iFrames nested, and my content is always the final nested one of course.

What I don't understand is that `document.body.webkitRequestFullScreen()` is well defined in my document but it returns `undefined`.

I'm making an hypothesis: Do all nested iFrames need to have the `allowFullScreen` attribute? Or Can the full-screen work if only the upper iFrame have it?

And if my problem comes from this attribute, is there a way to allowFullScreen to all parents iFrames of the document?

Comment: All that nesting is likely very problematic due to same origin policy. You might be better off providing link inside your iframe that would open your page in a new window using `window.open()`

Comment: It would be a workaround, but in this case the nesting is used to communicate with a SCORM API through the DOM.